# Dynamic Structs are failing

Tags: c#, dynamic, struct

I have a problem using a class of made of structures.

Here's the basic definition:

```
using System;

struct Real
{
    public double real;

    public Real(double real)
    { 
        this.real = real;
    }
}

class Record
{
    public Real r;
    public Record(double r)
    {
        this.r = new Real(r);
    }
    public void Test(double origval, double newval)
    {
        if (this.r.real == newval)
            Console.WriteLine("r = newval-test passed\n");
        else if (this.r.real == origval)
            Console.WriteLine("r = origval-test failed\n");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("r = neither-test failed\n");
    }
}
```

When I create a non-dynamic (static?) Record, setting the Real works.
When I create a dynamic Record, setting the real doesn't work.
When I create a dynamic Record, replacing the real works.

And here's the test program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double origval = 8.0;
        double newval = 5.0;

        // THIS WORKS - create fixed type Record, print, change value, print
        Record record1 = new Record(origval);
        record1.r.real = newval;        // change value  ***
        record1.Test(origval, newval);

        // THIS DOESN'T WORK.  change value is not making any change!
        dynamic dynrecord2 = new Record(origval);
        dynrecord2.r.real = newval;     // change value
        dynrecord2.Test(origval, newval);

        // THIS WORKS - create dynamic type Record, print, change value, print
        dynamic dynrecord3 = new Record(origval);
        dynamic r = dynrecord3.r;       // copy out value
        r.real = newval;                // change copy
        dynrecord3.r = r;               // copy in modified value
        dynrecord3.Test(origval, newval);

    }
}
```

And here's the output:
r = newval-test passed
r = origval-test failed
r = newval-test passed

When I change the struct Real to class Real, all three cases work.

So what's going on?
Thanks,
Max

Comment: Rule of thumb; **never make a mutable struct**. Even if you think it is sane, it probably isn't.

Comment: I should also add; public fields is a problem too: your code will behave differently if you switch to properties, which is unfortunate and to be avoided.

Comment: This code is obviously not for production. The public fields are just to strip it down to the simplest representation of the problem.

Comment: @Max - but it *is* very relevant to the problem; change the field to a property, and look at what the compiler tells you.

Comment: Marc,  I wrapped the field with a property.  The compiler didn't complain but the same failure occurs.

Comment: @Max: if I change to `public Real r { get; set; }` **and nothing else**, I get "Error 3 Cannot modify the return value of 'Record.r' because it is not a variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dynamic` is really a fancy word for `object` as far as the core CLI is concerned, so you are mutating a boxed copy. This is prone to craziness. Mutating a struct *in the first place* is really, really prone to error. I would simply make the struct immutable - otherwise you are going to get this *over and over*.

Comment: I've seen this explanation but I don't buy it.  What is a struct but a POD type?  Not being able to set a value in a struct field in a class is like saying you can't set an int field in a class. 
 
This code is used for handling very fast data acquisition. The overhead of heap allocation of every field in the record is unacceptable.

Comment: @Max - have you actually *measured* that? Heap allocation is also pretty damned quick (and if they are short-lived, then collection is equally inexpensive). Structs are **not** simply POD; they are intended for **values** - and a *value* never changes. Of course, if you dropped the `dynamic` it will work, **and will be faster**, so if *performance* is your goal you're already shooting yourself in the foot. But ultimately it is that point when (via dynamic) the struct gets boxed (at `.r`) that is causing the fail.

Comment: @Max - to make it explicit: you say you don't want to allocate on the heap, but ultimately you are using `dynamic`; that **is** heap allocation, since `dynamic` works against `object`. This causes it to get boxed, and you've lost what you were aiming for. Using an interface (except with a generic/interface-constraint) would **also** cause boxing.

Comment: Also I *think* that stucts can be allocated on the heap if they're used within a class, see Eric Lipperts blog for the info http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: @Matt - oh absolutely they can, but at that point you already *have* a heap object, so it is kinda moot. The more subtle ones are iterator blocks, anonymous methods, etc.

Comment: @Marc - cheers for the extra info, I just mentioned "..within a class", because that's the scenario Max used in his question.

Comment: The heap allocation issue is not the real point here.  Why doesn't "dynamic record" work the same way as "Record record"?

Comment: @Max - because with `Record record`, the expression `record.r` treats `r` as a value-typed field, which *can* be mutated in-place. With `dynamic record`, the expression `record.r` is *itself* typed as `dynamic` (which is, as already mentioned, a fancy word for `object`); thus `record.r` takes a **boxed copy** of the value, and then mutates the boxed copy. It *does not* mutate the original `struct`.

Comment: @Max - to further note; if `r` was a property instead of a field, it would take a *non-boxed* copy in the `get` - so it would still fail (actually the compiler would spot this and fail at compile - but obviously with `dynamic` you can't get this luxury as it doesn't attempt to validate until runtime)

Comment: see comment above.  making it a property makes no difference.

Comment: @Max - which field? If I change `Record.r` to a prop, I get compiler #fail. And (as mentioned before) it is `.r` that is the issue in all this - that is the interesting property (are you perhaps changing `Real.real`?)

Comment: I changed Real.real to property and the compiler accepted it.  I'll try your change.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work but it's besides the point.  I really want a class of structs so I can create my record using a single allocation.

Comment: @Max - then you simply can't use dynamic. Dynamic against structs involves boxing.

Comment: @Max - additionally, that isn't *besides* the point; it is **central** to the point; the whole issue here is the behaviour of mutable structs (which should be avoided in the first place, btw). The **only** time mutation works is of a *field*; anything else (a property, a boxed copy, etc) and it **cannot work** as you are mutating a copy.

Answer (score 0):

I dug a little deeper into this problem.  Here's an answer from Mads Torgersen of Microsoft.

---

From Mads:

This is a little unfortunate but by design. In

```
dynrecord2.r.real = newval; // change value
```

The value of dynrecord2.r gets boxed, which means copied into its own heap object. That copy is the one getting modified, not the original that you subsequently test.

This is a consequence of the very “local” way in which C# dynamic works. Think about a statement like the above – there are two fundamental ways that we could attack that:

1) Realize at compile time that something dynamic is going on, and essentially move the whole statement to be bound at runtime

2) Bind individual operations at runtime when their constituents are dynamic, returning something dynamic that may in turn cause things to be bound at runtime

In C# we went with the latter, which is nicely compositional, and makes it easy to describe dynamic in terms of the type system, but has some drawbacks – such as boxing of resulting value types for instance.

So what you are seeing is a result of this design choice.

---

I took another look at the MSIL.  It essentially takes

```
dynrecord2.r.real = newval;
```

and turns it into:

```
Real temp = dynrecord2.r;
temp.real = newval;
```

If dynrecord2.r is a class, it just copies the handle so the change affects the internal field.  If dynrecord2.r is a struct, a copy is made, and the change doesn't affect the original.

I'll leave it up to the reader to decide if this is a bug or a feature.

Max

Comment: Any decent introduction the C#/.net states that casting a valuetype to `object` boxes it. An most good C# programmers tell you that you shouldn't use mutable structs. If you make a struct mutable you better know what you're doing.

Comment: I've read this twice, and as far as I can tell there is nothing here that wasn't already in the answer and comments I gave earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Make your struct immutable and you won't have problems.

```
struct Real
{
    private double real;
    public double Real{get{return real;}}

    public Real(double real)
    { 
        this.real = real;
    }
}
```

Mutable structs can be useful in native interop or some high performance scenarios, but then you better know what you're doing.

Comment: That is exactly the problem.  I have a high throughput data acquisition app.  It may just be that I'll have to code it in C++/CLI or even dump .Net.  As far as knowing what I'm doing, I'm getting there.